# Display 3 post item in a for loop of bootstrap carousel in Microweber

Tags: php, for-loop, bootstrap-4

Hello i am trying to display 3 post item of bootstrap carousel in Microweber. I am trying my luck here as not much info can be found in microweber as i am stuck for a few days. Here is my code.

```
<?php if (!empty($data)): ?>
<script>mw.require("<?php print $config['url_to_module']; ?>css/style.css", true); </script>


<?php $rand = 'item_carousel_'.$params['id']; $id = 'carousel_'.$params['id']; ?>
<div id="<?php print $id; ?>" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <?php $count = -1; foreach($data  as $item): ?>
    <?php $count++; ?>
    <div class="carousel-item <?php if($count == 0){ print 'active ';} ?>">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="card mb-2">
          <?php if($item['tn_image']):  ?>
            <a href="<?php print $item['link'] ?>" class="post-list-item-img" style="background-image:url('<?php print $item['tn_image']; ?>')"> </a>
          <?php endif; ?>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="text-center card-title"><a href="<?php print $item['link'] ?>"><?php print $item['title'] ?></a></h4>
            <p class="card-text"><?php print $item['description']; ?></p>
          </div>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach ; ?>
  </div>

   <!--Controls-->

   <a class="carousel-control-prev " href="#<?php print $id; ?>" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="fas fa-chevron-circle-left fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>

  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#<?php print $id; ?>" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>

  <!--/.Controls-->
</div>

<?php else : ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Currently it is display like this
[image]

But i want it to display 3 image in a row and using the control to rotate the next 3 post item.

Answer (score 0):

1 - which template you are using?
2 - you can use  **slidesToShow: 3** in slick slider init

For example:

```
$('.multiple-items').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3
});
```